# ¿Como puedo obtener variables de la url desde otra pagina por php?

Tags: php

Buenas tardes amigos de Stackoverflow quisiera obtener dos variables de esta url:
http://localhost/proyecto/back-comentarios/chgpw.php?email=ejemplo@gmail.com&code=c69aa9b6b202ac65c0537372f3350075.

Deseo desde php poder obtener las variables email y code ya que intente obtenerla desde la pagina que llega de la dirección en este caso chgpw.php.

Intente por medio de $variable = $_GET['email']; Pero nada que me hace caso.

Comment: Pon el código qué tienes hecho, con una URL de tú servidor local no podemos visualizar nada. Saludos

Comment: En la página incluye la siguiente línea: **var_dump($_GET);** y cuéntanos lo que devuelve.

Comment: @Triby me devuelve esto array(2) { ["email"]=> string(24) "correo@gmail.com" ["code"]=> string(32) "c69aa9b6b202ac65c0537372f3350075"; Como logro sacar el email y el code ?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo:

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

Para realizar validaciones y procesos adicionales solo usa las variables creadas: **$email** y **$code**